# Phantomjs customHeaders referrer not detecting by javascript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to test a webpage which will detect referrer using `document.referrer` . I am using this code below

```
page = webpage.create();
  page.customHeaders = {
    "Referer" : "http://example.com"
  };
```

but It's not working!! `document.refferer` never detect referrer, visit from phantomjs .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that`page.customHeaders` determines what HTTP headers phantom browser **sends** to the server,  not the ones that are *received* by the browser, `document.referrer` returns the latter.

You may want to navigate to `http://example.com` first, then open the page you are after, preferably by dropping an `<a href="http://localhost/MyApp"/>` tag and then getting phantom to click it.

A note on usage, you also want to make sure the page is loaded before checking the `document` object.

Here is an example I wrote using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) as it abstracts all the async and event handling functionality making the code more readable.. Ie:

```
// Step 1, Navigate to http://example.com and drop a link to your app
casper.start("http://example.com", function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
       var link = document.createElement("A");
       link.id = "the-button";
       link.href= "http://localhost/MyApp";
       document.body.appendChild(link);
    });
});

// Step 2, pretend to click on link, evaluate referrer when loaded
casper.thenClick("a#the-button", function() {
    // The page is now loaded
    var referrer = this.evaluate(function() {return document.referrer; }
   console.log(referrer)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! I was misunderstood the `browser header ` but I have got some lights after your answer about header.